# Combined two table having different values for comparison

Tags: powerbi

I am new in Power BI and I have very strange problem, I know its data problem but we cannot change the data so if anyone can suggest any solution?

Problem:

I have two tables :

Table 1

```
Column 1    Column 2        Column 3
1           Fixing Test     1st May 2022
1           Frame Test      2nd May 2022
1           Test            3rd May 2022
```

Table 2

```
Column 1    Column 2    Column 3
1           Fix test        A
1           Frame Eco       B
1           Base            C
```

My problem is data is not same for column 2 ( some text can be same) Column 1 is same,I need following output in my report.

```
Table 2

    Column 1    Column 2    Column 3    Column 4
    1           Fix Test        A       1st May 2022
    1           Frame eco       B       2nd May 2022
    1           Base            C       3rd May 2022
```

Can anyone suggest any solution for this?

Comment: Why `Frame Eco/B` should appear next to `2nd May 2022` and not on the row with `3rd May 2022`?

Comment: You might be able to edit the query (`Home=>Transform`) either by including a lookup of equivalences, or perhaps by exploring the parameters of the `Table.FuzzyJoin` function